# Unable to activate NavigationLink programmatically, in a List ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

In a [simple test project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkProg/NaviLinkProg) I display a List of NavigationLink items:

[image: screenshot]

The file [GamesViewModel.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkProg/NaviLinkProg) simulates a list of numerical game ids, coming via Websockets in my real app:

```
class GamesViewModel: ObservableObject /*, WebSocketDelegate */ {
    @Published var currentGames: [Int] = [2, 3]
    @Published var displayedGame: Int = 0
    
    func updateCurrentGames() {
        currentGames = currentGames.count == 3 ?
            [1, 2, 3, 4] : [2, 5, 7]
    }

    func updateDisplayedGame() {
        displayedGame = currentGames.randomElement() ?? 0
    }
}
```

My problem is that I am trying to activate a random NavigationLink in the [ContentView.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkProg/NaviLinkProg) programmatically, when the Button "Join a random game" is clicked:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm:GamesViewModel = GamesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(vm.currentGames, id: \.self) { gameNumber in
                        NavigationLink(destination: GameView(gameNumber: gameNumber)
                                       /* , isActive: $vm.displayedGame == gameNumber */ ) {
                            Text("Game #\(gameNumber)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button(
                    action: { vm.updateCurrentGames() },
                    label: { Text("Update games") }
                )

                Button(
                    action: { vm.updateDisplayedGame() },
                    label: { Text("Join a random game") }
                )
          }
       }
    }
}
```

However, the code

```
ForEach(vm.currentGames, id: \.self) { gameNumber in
    NavigationLink(destination: GameView(gameNumber: gameNumber),
                   isActive: $vm.displayedGame == gameNumber ) {
        Text("Game #\(gameNumber)")
    }
}
```

does not compile:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding'

Is it even possible to use a `$` inside of a `ForEach`?

My context is that in my real app the Jetty backend creates a new game in the PostgreSQL database and then sends the numerical id of that new game to the app. And the app should display that game, i.e. navigate to the [GameView.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkProg/NaviLinkProg) programmatically.

**UPDATE:**

The users jnpdx and Dhaval have both suggested interesting solutions (thanks!) - however they only work for short Lists, when the NavigationLinks are visible at the screen.

For longer Lists when a NavigationLink should be activated for the game number which is scrolled offscreen - they do not work!

I have tried implementing my own solution, by using a NavigationLink/EmptyView at the top of the screen, to ensure that it is always visible and can be triggered to transition to the `vm.displayedGame` number.

However my code does not work, i.e. only works once (maybe I need to set `displayedGame = 0` somehow after navigating back to the main screen?) -

Here [ContentView.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkProg/NaviLinkProg):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm:GamesViewModel = GamesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(
                        destination: GameView(gameNumber: vm.displayedGame),
                        isActive: Binding(get: { vm.displayedGame > 0 }, set: { _,_ in })
                ) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                List {
                    ForEach(vm.currentGames, id: \.self) { gameNumber in
                        NavigationLink(
                                destination: GameView(gameNumber: gameNumber)
                            ) {
                            Text("Game #\(gameNumber)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button(
                    action: { vm.updateCurrentGames() },
                    label: { Text("Update games") }
                )
                Button(
                    action: { vm.updateDisplayedGame() },
                    label: { Text("Join a random game") }
                )
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you need a `Binding<Bool>` -- not just a simple boolean condition. Adding `$` gives you a binding to the `displayedGame` (ie an `Binding<Int?>`), but not a `Binding<Bool>`, which is what the `NavigationLink` expects.

One solution is to create a custom Binding for the condition you're looking for:

```
class GamesViewModel: ObservableObject /*, WebSocketDelegate */ {
    @Published var currentGames: [Int] = [2, 3]
    @Published var displayedGame: Int?
    
    func navigationBindingForGame(gameNumber: Int) -> Binding<Bool> {
        .init {
            self.displayedGame == gameNumber
        } set: { newValue in
            self.displayedGame = newValue ? gameNumber : nil
        }
    }
    
    func updateCurrentGames() {
        currentGames = currentGames.count == 3 ? [1, 2, 3, 4] : [2, 5, 7]
    }

    func updateDisplayedGame() {
        displayedGame = currentGames.randomElement() ?? 0
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm:GamesViewModel = GamesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(isActive: vm.navigationBindingForGame(gameNumber: vm.displayedGame ?? -1)) {
                    GameView(gameNumber: vm.displayedGame ?? 0)
                } label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                List {
                    ForEach(vm.currentGames, id: \.self) { gameNumber in
                        NavigationLink(destination: GameView(gameNumber: gameNumber),
                                       isActive: vm.navigationBindingForGame(gameNumber: gameNumber)
                        ) {
                            Text("Game #\(gameNumber)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button(
                    action: { vm.updateCurrentGames() },
                    label: { Text("Update games") }
                ).padding(4)

                Button(
                    action: { vm.updateDisplayedGame() },
                    label: { Text("Join a random game") }
                ).padding(4)
                
          }.navigationBarTitle("Select a game")
       }
    }
}
```

I changed `displayedGame` to an `Int?` because I think semantically it makes a little more sense to be an Optional rather than set to `0` if there's no displayed game, but that could easily be changed back if need be.

Comment: Yes, I actually wanted an `Int?` thank you :-)

Comment: IIRC, this will only work for the NavigationLinks visible on screen

Comment: Ouch, you are correct! Tested it with `Array(10..50)`. How to fix?

Comment: Apologies @jnpdx while I appreciate your answer, it does not work for longer Lists with NavigationLinks offscreen. I have to remove the green mark from your answer. And I have updated my question.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I've updated my answer -- you were on the right track adding a NavigationLink at the top, but you also have to use the `set` side of the Binding -- otherwise it'll only work once.

Comment: Thank you, I think that the second `isActive` in your updated answer is not needed (i.e. the List -> ForEach -> NavigationLink -> isActive is not needed). Because it is always the isActive of the EmptyView parent that is used for programmatically triggering the navigation to GameView

Comment: Maybe… I’d have to do some testing. There may be scenarios on iPad (or Mac) where two columns are shown and it would be important that the highlighting was still correct.

Comment: The highlighting in two-columns seems like it doesn't *really* work reliably with two-column navigation either way... Maybe there's another trick

Comment: Just 1 last question please: when do you think the `set` method of the `navigationBindingForGame` is called? Why is it important?

Comment: It is called when the user navigates back from the game page.

Answer (score 1):

You also pass like this

```
ForEach(vm.currentGames, id: \.self) { gameNumber in
    NavigationLink(destination: GameView(gameNumber: gameNumber),
                   isActive: Binding(get: {
                            vm.displayedGame == gameNumber
                        }, set: { (v) in
                            vm.displayedGame = v ? gameNumber : nil
                        })) {
        Text("Game #\(gameNumber)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that really work? The `.constant` will probably never change? I have tried your suggestion in [my test project](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/NaviLinkProg/NaviLinkProg) and it produces erratic behaviour after few clicks on the "Join a random game" button.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber l check my code and update answer please check

Comment: That works too! (Sadly, also only for the NavigationLinks shown on the screen). Thank you, upvoted